# R - nested loop for list of SpatialLinesDataFrame intersected with SpatialPolygonsDataFrame objects

Tags: r, for-loop, spatial, r-sp, rgdal

I have a series of steps I need to complete on a list of `SpatialLinesDataFrame` ('lines' herein) objects based on their relationships with individual features within a multi-feature `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` ('polygons') object. In short, each line list element originates inside a single polygon feature, and may or may not pass through one or more other polygon features. I want to update each line element to connect origin polygons to the first point of contact for each individual polygon intersected by the line element. So, each line element may become multiple new line features (n=number of intersected polygons).

I would like to do this efficiently as my lines lists and polygon features are numerous. I have provided example data and STEP-wise description of what I am trying to do below. I am new to R and not a programmer, so I don't know if any of what I propose is valid.

[image: example lines + polygons]

```
library(sp) 
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

###example data prep START
#example 'RDCO Regional Parks' data can be downloaded here: 
https://data-rdco.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets group_ids=1950175c56c24073bb5cef3900e19460 

parks <- readOGR("/path/to/example/data/RDCO_Regional_Parks/RDCO_Regional_Parks.shp")
plot(parks)

#subset watersheds for example
parks_sub <- parks[parks@data$Shapearea > 400000,]
plot(parks_sub, col='green', axes = T)

#create SpatialLines from scratch
pts_line1 <- cbind(c(308000, 333000), c(5522000, 5530000))
line1 <- spLines(pts_line1, crs = crs(parks_sub))
plot(line1, axes=T, add=T) #origin polygon = polyl[[4]] = OBJECTID 181

pts_line2 <- cbind(c(308000, 325000), c(5524000, 5537000))
line2 <- spLines(pts_line2, crs = crs(parks_sub))
plot(line2, axes=T, add=T) #origin polygon = polyl[[8]] = OBJECTID 1838

linel <- list()
linel[[1]] <- line1
linel[[2]] <- line2

#convert to SpatialLinesDataFrame objects
lineldf <- lapply(1:length(linel), function(i) SpatialLinesDataFrame(linel[[i]], data.frame(id=rep(i, length(linel[[i]]))), match.ID = FALSE))  

#match id field value with origin polygon
lineldf[[1]]@data$id <- 181
lineldf[[2]]@data$id <- 1838
###example data prep END

#initiate nested for loop
for (i in 1:length(lineldf)) {
  for (j in 1:length(parks_sub[j,])) {

#STEP 1:for each line list feature (NB: with ID matching origin polygon ID) 
#identify whether it intersects with a polygon list feature
    if (tryCatch(!is.null(intersect(lineldf[[i]], parks_sub[j,])), error=function(e) return(FALSE)) == 'FALSE'){
     next
    }
#if 'FALSE', go on to check intersect with next polygon in list
#if 'TRUE', go to STEP 2

#STEP 2: add intersected polygon OBJECTID value to SLDF new column in attribute table
#i.e., deal with single intersected polygon at a time
    else {
      lineldf[[i]]@data["id.2"] = parks_sub[j,]@data$OBJECTID

#STEP 3: erase portion of line overlapped by intersected SPDF
      line_erase <- erase(lineldf[[i]],parks_sub[j,])

#STEP 4: erase line feature(s) that no longer intersect with the origin polygon
#DO NOT KNOW HOW TO SELECT feature (i.e., line segment) within 'line_erase' object
      if (tryCatch(!is.null(intersect(line_erase[???], parks_sub[j,])), error=function(e) return(FALSE)) == 'FALSE'){
        line_erase[???] <- NULL}
      else {

 #STEP 5: erase line features that only intersect with origin polygon
           if (line_erase[???]@data$id.2 = parks_sub[j,]@data$OBJECTID){
             line_erase[???] <- NULL
           }
              else {
 #STEP 6: write valid line files to folder
        writeOGR(line_erase, 
                 dsn = paste0("path/to/save/folder", i, ".shp"),
                 layer = "newline",
                 driver = 'ESRI Shapefile',
                 overwrite_layer = T)
      }}}}}
```

Comment: Do you want to end up with lines that don't cross the polygons? ie they stop at the first side of any polygon they hit and then there's a new line starting from the far side? What if a line cuts across the same polygon twice, like it does in your two examples?

Comment: That URL gets me to a 404 not found page - its got a space in it. Download from here? https://data-rdco.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/rdco-regional-parks

Comment: https://data-rdco.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/rdco-regional-parks I just checked it and it works for me... you could try the following and click on 'RDCO Regional Parks': https://data-rdco.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?group_ids=1950175c56c24073bb5cef3900e19460

Comment: @Spacedman I would like to end up with single lines that extend from the origin polygon to the first point of contact with an intersected polygon. So, in the figure above, each line would turn into two lines, i.e., one line going from the origin polygon to the first intersected polygon, and a second line going from the origin polygon to the second intersected polygon.

Comment: Okay I think I get it now - the lines would overlap. I have some ideas but I'd rather do it using the new `sf` spatial classes rather than the `sp` ones. Conversion is possible both ways so that should be okay...

Comment: Great @Spacedman! I am open to all suggestions. Looking forward to your ideas.

Comment: The lines you create here don't obey "each line list element **originates** inside a single polygon feature" -- the first coordinate is at lower left and is outside any polygons, and the second coordinate is inside a polygon. I do now have a solution assuming you know which end you want to start from...

Comment: n my real data, each line does 'originate' (start) inside a polygon. My line data are actually least cost paths (LCPs) for surface water flow (i.e., modelling how water most likely flows overland when it starts from a specified location). So, I need to run the analysis separately for each of these 'start polygons' (every polygon in the list is a 'start polygon', and can also be intersected by the LCPs). Also, in my real data the LCPs are not straight lines - let me know if that changes your advice.

Comment: Okay so if I flip the order of points in your test lines such that the first point is always the one inside the polygon that more accurately describes your data?

Comment: And yes, if the lines aren't straight lines then all my code below is of no use whatsoever.

Comment: Yes - to your 'first point always inside the polygon' question. And apologies for not having an example that more accurately represents my data. I will create better sample data and re-ask. I hope it doesn't frustrate you and please know how sincerely I appreciate your help so far.

Comment: Maybe I'll have one more go but this needs absolute clarity. Your input lines are non-straight paths, but do you want your output lines to be the straight lines that connect the start to the polygon intersections, or do you want your output lines to be subsections of your original wiggly input lines?

Comment: The output lines need to be 'wiggly' too, i.e., follow the exact paths of the input lines. I am in the middle of trying to create more appropriate 'reproducible example' data, and will re-ask and send you the link asap. Thank you very much again for your patience with me.

Comment: There's a geopackage here with a poly and a line layer - let me know if its analogous to your problem and I'll work with it: https://lancaster.app.box.com/s/n417an71zpcal1sxkdmv9ribclhvnqd0

Comment: Thank very much for the suggestion, but I think my data are a little different. I have created some reproducible example data and have posted an updated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952083/r-crop-list-of-least-cost-paths-intersected-with-spatialpolygonsdataframe-obje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `sf` package. I'll work with the objects you create and convert them to `sf`, although you can read shapefiles into `sf` objects and create them from scratch so if there's no other reason to use `sp` objects I'd recommend that.

Use these packages:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
```

Convert polygons. I'm dropping a load of columns from `parks_sub` just so it can print neater - if you need them don't drop them:

```
p = st_as_sf(parks_sub)
p = p[,c("OBJECTID","PARK_NAME")]
```

Convert lines. I'm only going to work with your first line object, write a loop over your list to do a whole set:

```
l1 = st_as_sf(lineldf[[1]])
```

Next step is to compute all the intersection points between your line and your polygons. You have to: a) convert the polygons to linestrings otherwise the intersection of a polygon and a line is a line, and b) convert the "MULTIPOINT" intersections when a line crosses a polygon more than once into a set of POINT objects using `st_cast`:

```
pts = st_cast(st_cast(st_intersection(l1,
             st_cast(p,"MULTILINESTRING")
             ),"MULTIPOINT"),"POINT")
```

Next we need the first point of the line. For the data you create in the example, the line end in the polygon is actually the second point, so I'll extract that here.

```
first_point = st_cast(l1$geom,"POINT")[2]
```

If in your real data its the first point then put `[1]` in there. If it depends then that's another little problem.

Now compute the distances from that first point to all the intersection points:

```
pts$d_first = st_distance(first_point, pts)[1,]
```

So what we want now is the nearest intersection point in each group of points defined by the same polygon ID.

```
near_pts = pts %>% group_by(OBJECTID)  %>% filter(d_first==min(d_first))
```

Then the desired lines are constructed from the first point to those nearest points:

```
nlines = st_cast(st_union(near_pts, first_point),"LINESTRING")
```

Plot the polygons and the lines in decreasing width to show the overlap:

```
plot(p$geom)
plot(nlines$geom, lwd=c(10,7,4), col=c("black","grey","white"), add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Note the three lines include a short one (in white) from the first point to the boundary of the polygon it is in - if you don't want this you can filter out the point with the nearest distance from the data frame before constructing the lines - but that assumes the first point is inside a polygon...

`nlines` retains the attributes of the polygons the line intersects, as well as the ID of the line:

```
> nlines
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  LINESTRING
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 310276 ymin: 5522728 xmax: 333000 ymax: 5530000
epsg (SRID):    26911
proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=11 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
   id OBJECTID      PARK_NAME     d_first                       geometry
1 181     2254  Mission Creek  6794.694 m LINESTRING (326528.6 552792...
2 181     1831    Glen Canyon 23859.161 m LINESTRING (310276 5522728,...
3 181     1838 Black Mountain  1260.329 m LINESTRING (331799.6 552961...
```

so now wrap all that into a function and loop that over your lines and job done!?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. A few issues: (1) when I try to add nlines to the plot as you have done, I get this error msg: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'geom'....

Comment: (2) I also am not sure how to 'wrap all that into a function and loop that over [my] lines'. Would you please summarize how to do this using the code you created?

Comment: (3) Please also see my response to your comment above re: lines originating inside polygons. If this changes your answer at all please also let me know.

Comment: I can't teach you everything about R programming here, so you should upskill with some tutorials until you know how to do things like looping over lists and writing functions.